# scrapy: load item with variables

Tags: python, variables, scrapy, load

hello I am new to scrapy, I need to load 2 dates on a web. How do I put variables in items?

```
fecha_today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
fecha_yesterday = (datetime.date.today()- timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%m-%y")
```

This is my spider

```
def parse_date(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n ponemos las fechas \n\n\n")
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    link_fecha = hxs.select('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/a')
    date_item=  ItemLoader ( FechaItem ()) 
    date_item.add_path('fecha_today','/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span/input')
    date_item.add_path('fecha_yesterday','/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/span/input')

    return date_item.load_item()
```

What do I have to put in item.py so that the variables take me?
item.py

```
class    FechaLoader(scrapy.loader.ItemLoader):
```

I need to put these variables to then access a table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhecC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use item loader at all

I have been coding in Python Scrapy for 3+ years and I have never used it, just simply yield a dictionary like that

```
def parse_date(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n ponemos las fechas \n\n\n")
    item = {}

    item['fecha_today'] = response.xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span/input').extract_first()
    item['fecha_yesterday'] = response.xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/span/input').extract_first()

    yield item
```

Comment: but how do I put the variable to then access a table? What do I have to put in class item?

Comment: I understand your code, but how do I put a date yesterday and today on the web with scrapy? I do not have to extract the data but put it

Comment: you want to extract date from scraped page? just get the Xpath and do response.xpath("xpath here").extract_first() ... thats it

Comment: I need to put these variables to then scrapy to a table. Modify the theme with the picture of the fields

Answer (score 0):

I just came accross this issue. So the idea is that we need to put variables to itemLoader fields. We can add value to itemLoader by `add_value` method of ItemLoader object. Here is code.

```
fecha_today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
fecha_yesterday = (datetime.date.today()- timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%m-%y")

def parse_date(self, response):
self.log("\n\n\n ponemos las fechas \n\n\n")
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

link_fecha = hxs.select('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/a')
date_item=  ItemLoader ( FechaItem ()) 
date_item.add_value('fecha_today', str(fecha_today))
date_item.add_value('fecha_yesterday',str(fecha_yesterday))

return date_item.load_item()
```